# Extra term in $2+\epsilon$ expansion of sigma model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization, ising-model, critical-phenomena, sigma-models

I'm working through [David Tong's notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft.html) on Statistical Field Theory, in particular the $2+\epsilon$ expansion of the sigma model with free energy
$$F[\vec{n}]=\int d^dx \frac{1}{2e^2}\nabla\vec{n}\cdot\nabla\vec{n}$$
found on pages 119-120.

After renormalisation one finds
$$e^2(s)=\exp\left((d-2)s\right)\left(\frac{1}{e_0^2}+(2-N)\int_{\Lambda\exp(-s)}^\Lambda\frac{d^dq}{(2\pi)^d}\frac{1}{q^2}\right)$$
and we need to differentiate this to find the beta function $\frac{de}{ds}$.

Using the result that
$$\frac{d}{ds}\int_{\Lambda\exp(-s)}^\Lambda dq\,f(q)=\Lambda f(\Lambda)$$
I find that
$$\frac{de}{ds}=-\frac{\epsilon}{2}e+(N-2)\frac{e^3}{4\pi}\Lambda^\epsilon\exp(\epsilon s)$$
but Tong either doesn't get or disregards the $\exp(\epsilon s)$ at the end to get
$$\frac{de}{ds}=-\frac{\epsilon}{2}e+(N-2)\frac{e^3}{4\pi}\Lambda^\epsilon.$$

I know the beta function shouldn't depend on $s$, but I'm not sure why I can disregard that term.